# Android - vector drawable navigation drawer icon error despite adding vector drawable library support

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-icons, android-support-design

I'm trying to use vector drawables for navigation drawer icons, but I'm getting errors on pre-lollipop devices. I'm using `gradle 2.1.3`. Here's what I did:

I added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` and the appropriate dependencies:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
}
```

I  then added vector drawable .xml files (i.e., `ic_shopping_cart.xml`) to `res/drawable` folder.

I then use vector drawables in my navigation drawer menu xml (i.e., `activity_main_drawer.xml`) like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_shopping_cart"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
            android:title="Shopping Cart" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

This works fine on > API 21, but crashes on pre-lollipop devices because `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` disables the generation of PNGs on older devices. I can remove `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` from `build.gradle` so older devices can fallback to PNGs for nav drawer icons, but I don't want to do that unless I have no other choice.

I tried to change `app:icon` to `app:srcCompat` and add the app namespace (i.e., `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to my navigation drawer xml, but no icons would show.

Adding vector drawable library support might help with setting drawable vectors for `<ImageView>`, but what about `<item>` in menu layout?

Am I missing something? Or is it not supported? Or something else?

My question should not be considered a duplicate for similar questions relating to dealing with `app:src` attribute for`<ImageView>`. My issue is related to dealing with `android:icon` attribute for `<item>` tag in menu layout.

Comment: did you find the solution ? i have same problem ?

Comment: @pike - I did not. I couldn't find any information on this in the documentation nor on SO. My guess is that navigation drawer icons do not support vector drawables on pre-lollipop devices when adding vector drawable support library.

Comment: I am using build tools 25.0.0 and gradle 2.14.1 and vectors are working for me in nav drawer

Comment: @YashLadia - Did you test your nav drawer on prelollipop device/emulator? I'm curious if the vector icons fall back to png icons. Or whether no icons were show on pre-lollipop devices like it did for me.

Comment: Not having any pngs in my res, so no chance of falling back. And, I have tested it on pre-lollipop devices.